# How do I convert ifstream or string input to char?

Tags: c++, string, char

In this method,

```
void mainRoutine(char *pattern, string searchPattern)
{
        cout << "Please enter the string pattern to be searched: " << endl;
        getline(cin, searchPattern);
        ifstream filename(searchPattern.c_str());
        while(filename.good() && filename.peek() != EOF)
        {
                cout << (char)filename.get();
        }
        cout << "\n";
        char *pattern = (char *)filename;
}
```

When the user inputs a string - the filename to be taken in, I want to convert this string into a char so I can use it in other methods. How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of "convert this string into a char", do you perhaps mean convert it into a char pointer?

Comment: Making a `char*` from `std::string` is simple - call `c_str()` method on the string.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile on a respectable compiler. The last line: char *pattern = (char *)filename; is not valid. You could however grab a local, read-only char pointer to a string with: const char * pName = filename.c_str(); 
Bare in mind that the pointer is only valid inside the scope of the current function.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the `std::string`

```
std::string mainRoutine()
{
  std::string searchPattern;
  std::cout << "Please enter the string pattern to be searched: \n";
  std::cin >> searchPattern;

  std::cout << std::ifstream(searchPattern).rdbuf() << '\n';
  // searchPattern.c_str() if not using c++11

  return searchPattern
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* chFilNam = new char[fileName.length() + 1];
memcpy(chFilNam,fileName.c_str(),fileName.length());
```

Comment: You should use strcpy() instead. memcpy() won't copy the null terminator, thus leaving chFilNam in an invalid state to be used as a C string.